# how to store client output in JSON formate [SOCKETS]

Tags: python, sockets

i have server client model which is working fine i need to store the client output in JSON format so that i can send that information on my `HTML page`. Right now the output consist `6 variables` which are `username , IP , status , OS , date & time , total devices` so i need to store these `6 variables` which are available on client side and i need to store it in JSON format at server end.
My current output on server side looks like this.

`Device Added in wraith with IP:192.168.1.8 OS is : Linux at time 12/10/2020 00:29:45 with total devices :b'2\n'`

`Device Removed from wraith with IP:172.17.85.8 OS is : Linux at time 12/10/2020 00:29:45 with total devices :b'1\n'`

where `Added/Removed = status` , `wraith=username` , `192.168.1.8=IP` , `Linux=OS` , `12/10/2020 00:29:45 = date & time` and `total devices = 2`

i need to store this piece of information in `JSON` format for each new client when it connect or Removed to server.

like this:

```
 {
    "username": "wraith",
    "ipaddr": "192.168.1.8",
    "staus": "Added/Removed",
    "os": "Linux",
    "Time & Date": "12/10/2020 00:29:45",
    "total devices": "1",
    
}
```

this is my client code :

```
from socket import *
import subprocess,time
import socket
import platform
from datetime import datetime

host = 'localhost'  # '127.0.0.1' can also be used
port = 52000
now = datetime.now()
username = gethostname()
ipaddr = gethostbyname(username)
os = str(platform.system())
date_time = str(now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Connecting to socket
sock.connect((host, port))  # Connect takes tuple of host and port
sock.send(bytes('ping', 'utf-8'))
i = 0
def detect_device(previous):
    global i
    i += 1
    total = (subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)
    print(total)
    time.sleep(3)

# if conditon if new device add
    if total>previous:
        response = "Device Added in" + " " + username + " " + "with IP:" + ipaddr + " OS is : " + os + " at time " + date_time + " with total devices :" + str(total)
        sock.send(response.encode())
# if no new device add or remove
    elif total==previous:
        detect_device(previous)
# if device remove
    else:
        response = "Device Removed from" + " " + username + " " + "with IP:" + ipaddr + " OS is : " + os + " at time " + date_time + " with total devices :" + str(total)
        sock.send(response.encode())
# Infinite loop to keep client running.


while True:
    print('in while true loop')
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    if (data == b'pong'):
        while True:
            detect_device(subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)#subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)

sock.close()
```

And this is my server function/code where it receive and display data:

```
def recieve_message(conn):
    while True:
        try:
          msg = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
          if len(msg) != 0:
              print(msg)

        except:
          pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the information in a `dict`, and use **`json.dump`** to write it into an `open`ed file.